# Cannot login second user after "switch user", but can if using Ctrl+Alt+F1

Tags: login, gdm, 22.04, switch-user

For at least a year or so I have had problems with the "switch user" function on Ubuntu. If I log in (whether as "user1" or "user2") and click "switch user" I am taken to the GDM login screen as expected. After clicking the user I want to login as, and inputing the correct password, I get no further. The following happens:

*Prior to upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04* (i.e. when running 21.10, and I think also when I was running 21.04) I was stuck on a frozen black screen, and had to repeatedly hit Ctrl+Alt+Del to reboot the system.

*After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04*, there is a slight difference – one might even call it an improvement. Instead of a freeze, I get a black screen for a second or two, and I am then taken back to the GDM login screen. If I retry, I get the same result. However, if I instead of clicking "switch user" to get the GDM login screen just change the TTY by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 I can actually login as the second user (!!). Particularly the latter makes me hopeful that the issue can be solved. But I need help debugging, since I am unsure which logs I should look at, and what to look for.

**Additional info:**
The output of cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager is "/usr/sbin/gdm3"

Comment: Thanks for attempting to reproduce! Though I'm pretty sure it's not a bug, but something related to my specific configuration/setup. Thus I would be interested in tips on how to try and identify the cause, so that I can correct the issue without a full reinstall.

Comment: Tried this now, both on user1 and user 2, but the problem persists even with all three folders moved out of the way/replaced with defaults. I also tried creating a new user, and I'm getting the same loop when switching users regardless of whether I am log into the new user first or attempting to switch to it after logging in as user1/user2.

Comment: I am out of ideas.